# Populate UITableView from Array of Dictionaries Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I'm trying to populate UITableVIew from Array of Dictionaries. This is my tableView / cellForRowAt method.
myPosts is array with dictionaries inside. When I use [indexPath.row], It's changing the type to "Any" and cannot cast it in dict.
My question is how to access the value of dictionary key using indexPath?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    let activePosts = myPosts[indexPath.row]
    print(activePosts)
    cell.customCellUsername.text = myUser
    cell.customCellPost.text = 
    cell.customCellImage.image = 
    cell.customCellUserImage.image =
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the type casting is the issue you are facing in cellForRowAtIndexPath. While getting the dictionary from array, include the following code:

//Assuming the dictionaries in myPosts Array is of [String:String] type

```
if let postDictionary = myPosts[indexPath.row] as? [String:String] {
  print(postDictionary) //Will print the dictionary in the array for 
                        //  index as equal to indexpath.row
}
```

Thanks